# Segues conflict when clicking LogOut Button

Tags: ios, segue

I have two segues from one ViewController.

One is **supposed to run**(crashes for now) when clicking on LogOut Button (Go to LogIn ViewController), another one **runs**(works good) when clicking on thumbnail of a video.

Since I need to retrieve the video from the server and display it in the ViewController I'm heading to(WatchVideoViewController), I do the code below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // Get a reference to a destination View Controller
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WatchVideoViewController

        // Set the selected video property of the destination view controller
        detailViewController.selectedVideo = self.selectedVideo
    }
```

As you might guess this code runs when performing every segue, that's why my LogOut segue crashes.

```
Could not cast value of type 'AppName.LoginViewController' to 'Appname.WatchVideoViewController'.
```

Here are pieces of code where I call segues:

```
@IBAction func pressLogOutButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logOutSegue", sender: self)
    }


// Handle event when user selects a cell(thumbnail)

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // Take note of which video is selected
        self.selectedVideo = self.videos[indexPath.row]

        // Call the segue
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToVideo", sender: self)
    }
```

**Is there any way to avoid running prepareForSegue when calling pressLogOutButton? Thanks a lot!**

Comment: you can check if the value of identifier in prepareForSegue

Comment: @Misha Could you please show how it looks in code. 
I'm not sure where and how should I perform this check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your `prepareForSegue`

`if segue.identifier == "logOutSegue"`
// perform log out logic

Comment: Misha! You Rock! :) Thanks a lot!